# LSTM get next output with Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, rnn, prediction

So I'm learning RNN, and tried to do a prediction LSTM, but I do not understand how the output works. I have this LSTM RNN:

```
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, x_t.shape[2]), dropout=0.0, recurrent_dropout=0.0, stateful=False,   kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
lstm_model.add(Dense(25,activation='relu'))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.003)
lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)
```

and fit with:

```
history = lstm_model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=300, verbose=2, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    shuffle=False, validation_data=(trim_dataset(x_val, BATCH_SIZE),
                    trim_dataset(y_val, BATCH_SIZE)), callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

When I then try to predict using

```
gotten = lstm_model.predict(x_test_t[-500:],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Will I get only one new output? I'm very confused with the way you run and get predictions

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current model, you will indeed get a **single scalar output**. This is because the last layer is `Dense` with just 1 unit.

In other words, with this model you can map a sequence to a single value that may represent, e.g., the **label** of the series or its **next value** depending on what target you train the network on.

Comment: Thank you, I think I now understand better
So if I wanted a n-dimensional array has result I would have to change the net to have a layer with n units and create the appropriate expected result, and that would give me the result for the following n days?

Comment: That's the simplest way to do it, so in short yes.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)